# Perl: How get multiple regex captures in a structured way?

Tags: regex, perl, regex-group

I am trying to get all occurences of a group of patterns in an arbitrary string, much like this:

```
my $STRING = "I have a blue cat. That cat is nice, but also quite old. She is always bored.";

foreach (my @STOPS = $STRING =~ m/(?<FINAL_WORD>\w+)\.\s*(?<FIRST_WORD>\w+)/g ) {

  print Dumper \%+, \@STOPS;
}
```

But the outcome is not what I expected, and I don't fully understand why:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'FINAL_WORD' => 'old',
          'FIRST_WORD' => 'She'
        };
$VAR2 = [
          'cat',
          'That',
          'old',
          'She'
        ];
$VAR1 = {
          'FINAL_WORD' => 'old',
          'FIRST_WORD' => 'She'
        };
$VAR2 = [
          'cat',
          'That',
          'old',
          'She'
        ];
$VAR1 = {
          'FINAL_WORD' => 'old',
          'FIRST_WORD' => 'She'
        };
$VAR2 = [
          'cat',
          'That',
          'old',
          'She'
        ];
$VAR1 = {
          'FINAL_WORD' => 'old',
          'FIRST_WORD' => 'She'
        };
$VAR2 = [
          'cat',
          'That',
          'old',
          'She'
        ];
```

If there is no better solution I could live with what is in `@STOPS` in the end and omit the loop. But I would prefer to get every pair of matches separately, and I don't see a way.

But why then is the loop executed multiple times anyway?

Thank you in advance, and Regards,

Mazze

Comment: What is the outcome? What did you expect instead?

Comment: I held back from posting the full outcome, as it was rather long. Should I do that or try to describe the outcome?
What I expected is a bit vague, but documented above as what I am looking for: A way to get each matched pair separately, either in a variables or just a pair in `$1` and `$2` each run of the loop.

Comment: Can't be too long with only three sentences in your string.

Comment: I added the full output now.

Comment: `@STOPS` has four elements, and so `Dumper` output gets printed four times because that's how many times the `foreach` loop runs. Not sure why you're doing that, but it's just doing what you tell it to.

Comment: Maybe you want a `while` loop instead? (With the match done in scalar context, not list)

Comment: What do you want to see in the output ? `%+` is a system variable that is like the capture variables and others. all operations that write to them _overwrite_ them after each match

Comment: `But I would prefer to get every pair of matches separately, and I don't see a way.` well of course you could take a _LOOK_ after each match and get a pair. The fact is that doing that with a named variable has no advantage for 2 reasons: 1, the groups are sequenced and not out_of_order, 2. nothing you can do with the named hash members `$+{FINAL_WORD}` and `$+{FIRST_WORD}` after a match other than push them onto an array, certainly not into another _hash_. So, you've gleaned how to observe the match results after each match. This is a basic concept. The question is unclear what you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a `while` loop not a `for` loop:

```
while ($STRING =~ m/(?<FINAL_WORD>\w+)\.\s*(?<FIRST_WORD>\w+)/g ) {
    print Dumper \%+;
}
```

**Output**:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'FIRST_WORD' => 'That',
          'FINAL_WORD' => 'cat'
        };
$VAR1 = {
          'FIRST_WORD' => 'She',
          'FINAL_WORD' => 'old'
        };
```

The `for` loop gathers all the matches at once in `@STOPS` and `%+` is set to the last global match. The `while` loop allows you to iterate through each global match separately.

According to [perldoc perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html):

> The modifier `/g` stands for global matching and allows the matching
>   operator to match within a string as many times as possible. In scalar
>   context, successive invocations against a string will have `/g` jump
>   from match to match, keeping track of position in the string as it
>   goes along. You can get or set the position with the `pos()` function.

Comment: Thank you very much. This looks now obvious, but I found the use of a `for` loop somewhere online and was not able to think around it.
But one more question: `while` is also using an array context, just as `my @STOPS` before. However, here we get a loop iteration each `global match`. Do I understand that correctly?

Comment: The while loop does not use an array context, but a scalar context and the `g` modifier keeps track of the global matches. See my updated answer